# How to use a spring boot dependency functionality configured with it's own properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependencies

I have a Spring Boot project (project A) that has some main functionality. I have another Spring Boot projeect (project B) that has some custom functionality. I'm doing this because I have different clients that need different custom implementations, but all need the main functionality.

I'm uploading project a's jar to archiva (a private maven repository) and using it as a dependency in project b.

I'm adding project a's functionality with this configuration in my main class of project b:

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"<project_a>", "<project_b>"})`

The problem is that I want each project configured with its own properties files when I run project B (while also running project A functionality). Is that possible?

In both projects, the application properties file it's called application.properties, and has different profiles based on the environment is run --> application-dev.properties, application-test.properties, application-prod.properties.

This is the file structure of the JAR of project A:

```
-- bundles/
-- com/     (application files)
-- META-INF/
-- application.properties
-- application-dev.properties
-- application-test.properties
-- application-prod.properties
```

Comment: Is `{"<project_b>", "<project_b>"}` a typo?

Comment: @Sam Oh yes, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have two application.properties or at least I never tried to join them to be honest. But an easy solution (and clear) for your problem would be to have `project A` functionality published as a library (just a jar and its dependencies) and have `application A` depend on that plus the configuration specific to it in an `application.property` file.

Then you have a second `application B` depend on the same common jar plus additional `application B` specific functionality and also have its own configuration specific to both `application A` and `application B` in a joined `application.properties` file.

A bit of duplication but it will work. With a bit of structural organization of that file it would not even be a messy thing. Something like below:

```
application.properties:

# application A specific: 
...

# application B specific:
...
```

If you don't have to have both files called `application.properties` another way would be to have a separate file for each application say you have `application-a.properties` and `application-b.properties` then in each application you create its own `@Configuration` class pointing to its own related properties file like below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-a.properties")
public class ApplicationAConfig {
    //...
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-b.properties")
public class ApplicationBConfig {
    //...
}
```

Then you use the two `Configuration` beans to build up your other beans in each of your applications. This will make it a bit harder to have it environment specific but of course you can manipulate (copy) files at deploy time.

Another way would be to pass it as a `spring.config.location` system property when running the app.

I don't know your running environment but for the last two solutions there are devops steps to include so it will run the way you want. Say if you ran as docker images you will have some commands to execute in dockerfile, and so on

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Application A doesn't need a specific configuration.  Application B does.

The problem is that if I replicate the configuration of A in B, I wouldn't even need project A because B has all it's functionality (and configuration), if I understand correctly. 

The thing is how to delegate the responsability of the configuration of A to A, and of B to B. I will have many applications "B" that depend on A, and it doesn't seem correct to duplicate in each the configuration of A (but if it comes to that, I won't have any other choice).

Comment: Added two more solutions to your problem. Each one requires extra work but they both should do the job.

Comment: The second solution worked just fine! Thanks